# Concatenating translatable strings is not allowed, use placeholders instead and only one string literal

Tags: testing

The following code:

```
$report .= '<p>' . t('<strong>%percentage</strong> of <strong><em>'.$node_type_get_types[$type]->name.'</em></strong> completed.', array('%percentage' => $percentage)) . ' ' . $count . '</p>';
```

is inside of iteration, because I need to make the same calculations and collect all the results and output all in one string.

Drupal.org's automated testing complains about the above part:

`Concatenating translatable strings is not allowed, use placeholders instead and only one string literal`

I don't have any idea how to make this correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you have to use a placeholder, in the same way you used the *%percentage* placeholder.

```
$report .= '<p>' . t('<strong>%percentage</strong> of <strong><em>@content-type</em></strong> completed. %count', array('%percentage' => $percentage, '@content-type' => $node_type_get_types[$type]->name, '%count' => $count)) . '</p>';
```

I used a @-placeholder for the content type, in the same way done from [`node_add()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7.x).

For a list of the placeholder types used from Drupal, see [`format_string()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7.x). The documentation for [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7.x) explain in details why concatenating is not possible in translatable strings.